# XCode 3.2 configuration still accessing OS X 10.4 framework when 10.5 is selected

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks

I wanted to try and use some features introduces in 10.5 (like Core Text), so I set the Base SDK and Deployment target both to Mac OS X 10.5
I am also certain that all referenced Frameworks have a path relative to the selected SDK, and the tooltip also currently says it is looking in the 10.5 folder.

When I try to compile it however, I get various warninings and errors that make it look like it is still referencing 10.4:

`/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h:1492:0 /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h:1492: warning: 'OTSetNBPEntityFromAddress' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h:1172)`

`.../code/utils/modules/Skins/SkinFont.h:36:0 .../code/utils/modules/Skins/SkinFont.h:36: error: 'CTFontRef' does not name a type`

What's even stranger is that this is not working in the 'Debug' configuration, but it is successfully working in another configuration.
I compared all configuration settings, but I couldn't find any difference.

Does anyone know if there is another place I should be looking for this?

Edit: I did found one similar problem from someone else, but unfortunately there are no useful replies yet:
http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2009/Sep/msg00200.html

Edit2: Here is the compiler output, I've removed some of the warnings since there were about 50 deprecated functions mentioned.

`CompileC build/Test10_4.build/Debug/djDecks_Mac.build/Objects-normal/i386/DJDecksVideoRenderer.o ../code/utils/modules/djDecks/DJDecksVideoRenderer.cpp normal i386 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42
cd /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 -x c++ -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -pipe -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O0 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -DHAVE_STRERROR -DUSEFFMPEG -D__MACOSX__ -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -mfix-and-continue -msse3 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -gdwarf-2 -I/Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/build/Test10_4.build/Debug/djDecks_Mac.build/djDecksForMac.hmap -F/Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/build/Debug -F/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -I/Users/gwenroelants/code/lib/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -I/Users/gwenroelants/code/lib/flac/src/libFLAC/include -I/Users/gwenroelants/code/lib/flac/include -I/Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/build/Debug/include -I/Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/build/Test10_4.build/Debug/djDecks_Mac.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/build/Test10_4.build/Debug/djDecks_Mac.build/DerivedSources -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -include /var/folders/Hh/Hhx2ce3OHReLY+QJa3OmM++++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/Test10_4_Prefix-cqnssmqwhfbgbtdcgyppeyqdmggp/Test10_4_Prefix.pch -c /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/djDecks/DJDecksVideoRenderer.cpp -o /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/build/Test10_4.build/Debug/djDecks_Mac.build/Objects-normal/i386/DJDecksVideoRenderer.o
Headers/OSServices.h:46,
                 from /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:28,
                 from /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Headers/AudioFile.h:27,
                 from /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Headers/AudioToolbox.h:22,
                 from /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/AudioDecoder/AudioDecoder.h:37,
                 from /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/Audio/player.h:10,
                 from /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/Audio/FModPlayer.h:9,
                 from /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/djDecks/DJDecksPlayer.h:9,
                 from /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/djDecks/DJDecksVideoRenderer.h:9,
                 from /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/djDecks/DJDecksVideoRenderer.cpp:7:
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h: In member function 'OSStatus TInternetServices::StringToAddress(char*, InetHostInfo*)':
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h:581: warning: 'OTInetStringToAddress' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h:504)
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h: In member function 'OSStatus TInternetServices::Query(char*, UInt16, UInt16, char*, OTByteCount, void**, OTByteCount, OTFlags)':
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h:596: warning: 'OTInetQuery' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h:571)
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h:596: warning: 'OTInetQuery' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h:571)
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h: In member function 'OSStatus TAppleTalkServices::GetMyZone(TNetbuf*)':
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h:903: warning: 'OTATalkGetMyZone' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h:846)
OpenTransportProviders.h:1492: warning: 'OTSetNBPEntityFromAddress' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h:1172)
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h:1492: warning: 'OTSetNBPEntityFromAddress' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Headers/OpenTransportProviders.h:1172)
In file included from /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/Skins/SkinObject.h:15,
                 from /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/Skins/SkinTab.h:10,
                 from /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/Skins/SkinTabGroup.h:11,
                 from /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/Skins/SkinWindow.h:12,
                 from /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/Skins/Skin.h:12,
                 from /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/djDecks/DjDecks.h:11,
                 from /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/djDecks/DJDecksPlayer.h:16,
                 from /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/djDecks/DJDecksVideoRenderer.h:9,
                 from /Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/djDecks/DJDecksVideoRenderer.cpp:7:
/Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/Skins/SkinFont.h: At global scope:
/Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/Skins/SkinFont.h:36: error: 'CTFontRef' does not name a type
/Users/gwenroelants/Test10_4/../code/utils/modules/Skins/SkinFont.h:37: error: 'CTFontRef' does not name a type`

Comment: There is a reply to that issue from Apple support asking for more information. The error message which you have given and the linking ine from the build which you have not

Comment: It wasn't my question on the apple list, and I am not subscribed to the mailing list so I can't add replies there either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the configuration that's not working, type "10.4" into the Build Settings search field and see what comes up. I expect the Framework Search Paths build setting has an explicit path to the 10.4 SDK somewhere.

It would indeed be helpful to have the text of the compiler invocation, just drag and drop the "Compiling" build step that's failing.

UPDATE

Thanks for posting the log.  It's very clearly in there:

```
-F/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks
```

That means that you have a Framework Search Path pointing directly into the 10.4u SDK even when you're using the 10.5 SDK.  You have to go through your target and project Framework Search Path and find this path and delete it.

Comment: I added the compiler output to the question.
Searching for 10.4 shows the Mac OS X Deployment target setting, which is a little strange since it is clearly set at Mac OS X 10.5
It also brings this up on the configuration that is working though...

Comment: Update: I managed to fix it by editing the project configuration files in a text editor and changing the 10.4 references to 10.5 there.

Answer (score 2):

i was having the same problem. And my solution...

Go to Project->Edit project settings...and look for Base SDK (under Architectures). Since i am using 10.6 i changed mine to "Mac OS X 10.6" and things started working.

Answer (score 0):

My guess (from my own experience) is that the target, project and configuration don't all agree. I still haven't figured out which one takes precedence over the other...